# Lombokython - Automatic __eq__, __hash__, __repr__

Tags: python, unit-testing, meta-programming

I recently decided to code some in Python after coding in Java using [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok) for quite some time. However, I got bit real hard when I forgot to implement `__eq__`, since Lombok normally does it for you.

I decided to try to implement something similar to Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode`, which I called `eqhash`. Then, I added a similar way to generate a `__repr__` method.

How well did I follow python style? I developed this using TDD, so I would like to know how my tests are as well.

**genmethods.py**

```
def eqhash(cls: type):
    """Adds __eq__, __ne__, and __hash__ methods to the class"""
    class NewCls(cls):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            if self is other: return True
            if not isinstance(other, NewCls): return False
            svars = vars(self)
            ovars = vars(other)
            return svars == ovars

        def __ne__(self, other):
            return not (self == other)

        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(vars(self).values())

    return _pass_attrs(NewCls, cls)


def repr_(cls: type):
    """Adds a __repr__ method to the class"""
    class NewCls(cls):
        def __repr__(self):
            return '{clsname}({variables})'.format(
                clsname=cls.__name__,
                variables=', '.join(repr(o) for o in vars(self).values())
            )

    return _pass_attrs(NewCls, cls)


def _pass_attrs(new_cls, cls):
    new_cls.__name__ = cls.__name__
    new_cls.__qualname__ = cls.__qualname__
    for attr, value in vars(cls).items():
        try:
            setattr(new_cls, attr, value)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return new_cls
```

**test_genmethods.py**

```
import unittest
import genmethods


class SData:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def test(self):
        return self._value


def ensure_not_mangled(self: unittest.TestCase, cls: type, name: str):
    self.assertEqual((1, 2), cls((1, 2)).test())
    self.assertEqual(name, cls.__name__)


class EqHashTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @genmethods.eqhash
    class Data(SData):
        pass

    def test_eq_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual(EqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), EqHashTest.Data((1, 2)))
        self.assertNotEqual(EqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), EqHashTest.Data((1, 4)))

    def test_hash_genned(self):
        v1 = EqHashTest.Data(1)
        v2 = EqHashTest.Data(1)
        self.assertEqual(hash(v1), hash(v2))

    def test_not_mangled(self):
        ensure_not_mangled(self, EqHashTest.Data, "Data")


class ReprTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @genmethods.repr_
    class Data(SData):
        pass

    def test_repr_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual('Data(1)', repr(ReprTest.Data(1)))

    def test_not_mangled(self):
        ensure_not_mangled(self, EqHashTest.Data, "Data")


class ReprEqHashTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @genmethods.repr_
    @genmethods.eqhash
    class Data(SData):
        pass

    def test_eq_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual(ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)))
        self.assertNotEqual(ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 4)))

    def test_hash_genned(self):
        v1 = ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)
        v2 = ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)
        self.assertEqual(hash(v1), hash(v2))

    def test_repr_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual('Data(1)', repr(ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)))

    def test_not_mangled(self):
        ensure_not_mangled(self, EqHashTest.Data, "Data")


class EqHashReprTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @genmethods.eqhash
    @genmethods.repr_
    class Data(SData):
        pass

    def test_eq_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual(ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)))
        self.assertNotEqual(ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 2)), ReprEqHashTest.Data((1, 4)))

    def test_hash_genned(self):
        v1 = ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)
        v2 = ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)
        self.assertEqual(hash(v1), hash(v2))

    def test_repr_genned(self):
        self.assertEqual('Data(1)', repr(ReprEqHashTest.Data(1)))

    def test_not_mangled(self):
        ensure_not_mangled(self, EqHashTest.Data, "Data")
```

Comment: ... And now I went and improved it to take optional arguments ala Lombok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. It would be substantially simpler to use a *mixin* instead of a decorator.
2. The test for equality is not symmetric: you have `a == b` if `b` belongs to a subclass of `a`'s class, but not vice versa. So it's possible to have `a == b` but `b != a`, which makes no sense.

   There are two sensible things to do here: either (i) ignore the class relationship, so that two objects compare equal if their `vars` are equal, regardless of which class they belong to; or (ii) insist that classes match, so that two objects compare equal only if they belong to the same class.
3. The intention seems to be for `eqhash` objects to hash based on their instance attributes, so that instances with different attributes get different hashes. But the code doesn't work! Here are two objects with different instance attributes, but whose hashes are the same:

   ```
   >>> @eqhash
   ... class Data(SData):
   ...     pass
   >>> d = Data(1)
   >>> hash(d)
   -9223372036573986785
   >>> e = Data(2)
   >>> hash(e)
   -9223372036573986785
   ```

   And here is one object that has different hashes at different times:

   ```
   >>> d = Data(1)
   >>> hash(d)
   -9223372036573986785
   >>> vars(d).values()
   dict_values([1])
   >>> hash(d)
   -9223372036574014153
   ```

   The problem is that you are constructing a `dict_values` object and then taking its hash. But `dict_values` objects don't hash based on their contents, only on their `id` (see [Python issue 22192](http://bugs.python.org/issue22192)), so the hash doesn't tell you anything about the values, only about the location in memory of the `dict_values` object.

#### 2. Revised code

```
class EqHash:
    """Mixin adding __eq__, __ne__, and __hash__ methods."""
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self is other
                or (type(self) == type(other)
                    and vars(self) == vars(other)))

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(vars(self).items())))

class Repr:
    """Mixin adding a __repr__ method."""
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{name}({values})'.format(
            name=type(self).__name__,
            values=', '.join(map(repr, vars(self).values())))
```

#### 3. Answers to questions

1. [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) is a decorator becuase it looks at the class in order to determine which ordering method was provided. See [the implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/functools.py#l192), which calls `getattr(cls, op, None)`. It would be much harder to do this in a mixin.
2. I spotted the problems by thinking carefully!

   First, equality is a symmetric relation, but `isinstance` is asymmetric, so it was suspicious that one was implemented using the other.

   Second, it only makes sense to implement `__hash__` on immutable objects, but the values of a dictionary are mutable, so this was also suspicious. See the [documentation for `__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), where it says:

   > If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__` method, it should not implement `__hash__`, since the implementation of hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Comment: Why is [total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) a decorator then? Is it because it allows the definition of an unspecified method?

Comment: What mentality could I have used in testing to catch the `__hash__` or `__eq__` errors?

Comment: @Justin: See revised answer.